# antd Table with switch component

Tags: antd

Is it possible to get row information by switching the switch in ant design table?

https://codesandbox.io/s/mmvrwy2jkp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the second argument of the render function is the record.
you can do this

```
{
  title: 'switch',
  dataIndex: 'age',
  key: 'age',
    render: (e, record) => (< Switch onChange={() => handleSwitchChange(record)} defaultChecked={e} />)
}
```

Comment: i won't get  switch current value, i need both  switch current value and row record.  https://codesandbox.io/s/lr0jmywzqq

Comment: You already have switch onChange, how about just `onChange={(switchValue) => handleSwitchChange(record, switchValue)` https://codesandbox.io/s/7mpon77220

Answer (score 0):

This is how I dealed with the switch component on each row item when using  Ant design. Maybe this could give you some hints.

**Table Columns**

```
const COLUMN =
     {
          title: 'Status',
          key: 'status',
          dataIndex: 'status',
          // status is the data from api 
          // index is the table index which could be used to get corresponding data
          render: (status, record, index) => {
            const onToggle = (checked) => {
              status = checked;
              onActiveUser(index, status);
            };
            return (
              <Space>
                <Switch defaultChecked={status} onChange={onToggle} />
              </Space>
            );
          },
        },

   const onActiveUser = (index, status) => {
        axios.patch({ id: users[index].id }, { is_active: status })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.log('Failed!');
          });
      };
```